# Why isn't this RequireJS shim working for react-router

Tags: requirejs, reactjs, react-router

I am trying to get react and react-router loading into my app via require.  I have to following shim setup, but I still get an error where react-router isn't getting a proper React object.

```
  paths:   {
    domReady:       '../lib/requirejs-domready/domReady',
    react:          '../lib/react/react',
    'react-router': '../lib/react-router/dist/react-router'
  },
  shim:    {
    'react':        {
      exports: 'React'
    },
    'react-router': {
      deps:    ['react'],
      exports: 'ReactRouter'
    }
  }

  require(['domReady!', 'react', 'react-router'], ...


Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'createClass' of undefined react-router.js:372
../utils/withoutProperties react-router.js:1
s react-router.js:1
(anonymous function) react-router.js:62
./Route react-router.js:1
s react-router.js:1
(anonymous function) react-router.js:886
./actions/LocationActions react-router.js:1
s react-router.js:1
e react-router.js:1
(anonymous function) require.js:1658
context.execCb require.js:874
Module.check require.js:1151
Module.enable require.js:782
Module.init require.js:1178
callGetModule require.js:1552
context.completeLoad require.js:1679
context.onScriptLoad
```

Everything installed via Bower.  React is 0.11.1, router is 0.7.0

Comment: Did you use `bower` to install `react-router`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It appears in the source that react-router will only work if `window.React` or `global.React` are set.  React itself will not expose a `global` object in a RequireJS environment.  So I ended up writing a shim.

```
paths:   {
  domReady:       '../lib/requirejs-domready/domReady',
  react:          '../lib/react/react',
  'react-router': '../lib/react-router/dist/react-router',
  'react-router-shim': 'react-router-shim'
},
shim:    {
  'react-router-shim': {
    exports: 'React'
  },
  'react-router': {
    deps:    ['react-router-shim'],
    exports: 'ReactRouter'
  }
}
```

react-router-shim:

```
define(['react'], function(React) {
  "use strict";

  window.React = React;
});
```

I can then use react and react-router as proper dependencies.

Comment: I've done this. But can't get the requirejs optimizer to work with it. When its all bundled it trows me: ```Uncaught Error: app missing react-router``` in the browser console.

Comment: @Spoeken Sorry, I haven't added r.js optimization to the project yet, so I can't help there.  If you find a solution, please do post an answer or edit this one.

Comment: Posted a question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28172896/missing-react-router-after-bundling

Comment: Good workaround.  I find this also works without an actual shim module, by using an `init` function: `shim: { "react-router": { deps: ['react'], exports: 'ReactRouter', init(React) { window.React = React; } } }`